# React native switch screen one component to another on button press

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, native

I am new in react native, making a basic app that will find no of cases of corona in every country 
so i have made 2 component both on separate file. how to switch from child to child component ?
Now i want to switch between them when i click on a button using stack navigator

**App.js**

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Splash from './scenes/splash';
import Corona from './scenes/corona';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Splash">
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Corona" component={Corona} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**splash.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button} from 'react-native';

export default function splash({navigation}) {
    return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image 
                source={require('../assets/corona.jpg')} 
                resizeMode="cover" style={styles.img} />
                <Text style={styles.txt}>
                    Track the current status {"\n"} 
                    of the COVID-19 and{"\n"}
                    stay up to date.</Text>
                <Text 
                style={styles.btn}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Corona')}
                >Continue</Text>
            </View>
    )
}
```

**corona.js (navigate to here)**

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button} from 'react-native';

export default function corona({navigation}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <View>
                <Text>Hello next screen</Text>
            </View>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In splash.js**

change

```
 <Text style={styles.btn}
  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Corona')}>Continue</Text>
```

to

```
   <Text style={styles.btn}
  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Corona')}>Continue</Text>
```

**And in corona.js**

Remove `<div>` tags in return, react-native doesn't support div tags

Hope this helps!